# Algorithmically finding mixed-derivative coefficients using finite differences

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, finite-differences

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable (for simplicity, let's assume ${C}^\infty$) function, and I would like to find the following partial derivatives numerically (at an arbitrary point):

$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}, \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial^2 x_i \partial x_k}, \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j \partial x_k}
$$

up to some order in the accuracy (say, $\mathcal{O}(\Delta x_i^{q_i}, \Delta x_j^{q_j})$ for the former, $\mathcal{O}(\Delta x_i^{q_i}, \Delta x_j^{q_j}, \Delta x_k^{q_k})$ for the latter, where $q_i, q_j, q_k \in \mathbb{N}$).
For $i = j = k$, I can just use the finite difference coefficients (see for instance the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient)), and then for $i \neq j \neq k$ I suppose I could iteratively apply the above provedure, but this may be numerically unstable.
I could instead simply write down the coefficients by hand (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1259743), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/418883), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1496583) for related questions), but this quickly becomes unfeasible and rather error-prone for higher orders in accuracy, especially for the third mixed derivative, so I'm wondering if there is a multi-parameter generalization (i.e. for $i \neq j \neq k$) to the above so I can algorithmically generate the coefficients to some given order in accuracy of each parameter.
For instance, if $n=2$, and I'm looking for $\partial_x \partial_y f$ up to $\mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2, \Delta y^2)$, I should get as output the 2-tuple of points $[(1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1)]$ and their corresponding coefficients $[1/4, -1/4, -1/4, 1/4]$ (as per [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1259743)).
Any advice or references would be appreciated!

Comment: see https://mathoverflow.net/q/423786/11260